Using CDC with BigQuery Storage Write Api in C#
I try to use the google.cloud.bigquery.storage.v1 nuget package to write data to my BigQuery tables with CDC and get an error as a result "The given value is not a valid CHANGE_TYPE in insert mode: UPSERT".
I set up my BigQuery Tables with primary keys. And then started building a proto file on basis of my json schema used to create the tables, the API returned an error telling me that the I'm missing a field indicating the change type for each row. The value set here should either be upsert or delete.
So I added this field and now I'm stuck with a new error which tells me "The given value is not a valid CHANGE_TYPE in insert mode: UPSERT".
So how do I use the storage write Api with cdc in c#?
